# Connect to Shopify to OrderCloud?

Tags: shopify, ordercloud

Can I connect my shopify store to an ordercloud account? I'm trying to determine if it's possible to connect my shopify store to an existing ordercloud account.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by connecting Shopify and OrderCloud?

Comment: Yes. I already have a Shopify store set up and our corporate office is wanting to connect our store to their vendor portal that runs on OrderCloud.

Comment: Shopify and OrderCloud are both ecommerce platforms so there is no way to connect the two. You would have to import your products into OrderCloud using the API in order to have them available for purchase in a marketplace. If your corporate office is already an OrderCloud customer, they should reach out to their account rep for any assistance.